# Continuously monitoring network connections

Tags: linux, networking, lsof, audit

I am looking for a network monitoring tool that can monitor all opened network connections in real-time and its output is easy to parse. What I want to achieve is auditing all in/out network connections and save the results into the remote database.

I am thinking about using the lsof for checking network connections:

```
lsof -i -r 1
```

Problem with the lsof is, that you can't set repeat mode lower than 1 sec and I am not sure if some short-lived connection, which not be shown by the lsof output, could be made during this period. It can happen? Or do you have some recommendation for another network monitoring tool?

Thanks

Comment: `iftop` for something graphical, or `netstat`

Comment: This might help, though i am not sure how easy it would be parse the outputs here: https://superuser.com/questions/604998/monitor-tcp-traffic-on-specific-port

Comment: Reading connection status from tcpdump looks like best option. Thanks for replies. ;)